# Passing event and model property from view to javascript function

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, devexpress-mvc

I use Devexpress grid and ASP.NET MVC. In one view I have an image, and on hovering it I want to call javascript function passing event and one model property.

Here is my code:

```
column.SetDataItemTemplateContent( c =>
{
    string errorMessage = DataBinder.Eval( c.DataItem, "Errors" ).ToString();
    if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(errorMessage))
    {
        ViewContext.Writer.Write( "<div style = 'cursor: pointer;' onmouseover='ShowErrorMessage(event, " + errorMessage + ")'><img id='errImg' src='../../Content/Images/error.png' /></div>" );
    }
} );
```

But it does not come into event handler. If I remove second parameter from ShowErrorMessage and leave just event, it's working. But how to pass errorMessage too?

Answer (score 1):

The code will interpret your string as a variable name try

```
ViewContext.Writer.Write( "<div style = 'cursor: pointer;' onmouseover='ShowErrorMessage(event)" + errorMessage + "'><img id='errImg' src='../../Content/Images/error.png' /></div>" ); }
```

Comment: Ah, yes I missed something, the new edit should do it.